# C multiple single line declarations

Tags: c, variables, declaration

What happens when I declare say multiple variables on a single line? e.g.

```
int x, y, z;
```

All are ints. The question is what are y and z in the following statement?

```
int* x, y, z;
```

Are they all int pointers?

Comment: Edited question, as it has nothing to do with Objective C

Comment: I know there's a duplicate of this question somewhere on here (I've definitely read this before)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Only `x` is a pointer to int; `y` and `z` are regular ints.

This is one aspect of C declaration syntax that trips some people up.  C uses the concept of a *declarator*, which introduces the name of the thing being declared *along with additional type information not provided by the type specifier*.  In the declaration

```
int* x, y, z;
```

the declarators are `*x`, `y`, and `z` (it's an accident of C syntax that you can write either `int* x` or `int *x`, and this question is one of several reasons why I recommend using the second style).  The int-ness of `x`, `y`, and `z` is specified by the type specifier `int`, while the pointer-ness of `x` is specified by the declarator `*x` (IOW, the expression `*x` has type `int`).

If you want all three objects to be pointers, you have two choices.  You can either declare them as pointers explicitly:

```
int *x, *y, *z;
```

or you can create a typedef for an int pointer:

```
typedef int *iptr;
iptr x, y, z;
```

Just remember that when declaring a pointer, the `*` is part of the variable name, not the type.

Comment: Truly a complete answer and to that of the underlying question of whether the * is for the type or the variable.

Answer (score 9):

In your first sentence:

```
int x, y, z;
```

They are all `int`s.

However, in the second one:

```
int* x, y, z;
```

Only `x` is a pointer to `int`. `y` and `z` are plain `int`s.

If you want them all to be pointers to `int`s you need to do:

```
int *x, *y, *z;
```

Comment: This is one reason the spacing `int* foo;` is really misguided. In this question's example, it makes it look like the 3 variables are all of type "`int*`". I would say this spacing is almost as offensive as `a+b * c`.

Answer (score 8):

Only x is an int pointer. Y and Z will be just int.
If you want three pointers:

```
int * x, * y, * z;
```

Answer (score 4):

It is important to know that, in C, declaration mimics usage. The * unary operator is right associative in C. So, for example in `int *x` x is of the type pointer to an int (or int-star) and in `int x`, x is of type int.

As others have also mentioned, in `int* x, y, z;` the C compiler declares x as an int-star and, y and z as integer.