# Declaring more than one variable in a single line

Tags: c, variables, gcc, mingw

I am new to coding, and my team mates mentioned that I should not declare more than one variable in a single line.
I code in C, and I noticed alot of documentation doing that, i.e:

```
int i, j, k;
```

is there a real reason behind declaring in a single line sometimes and other times not?

on the other side, I tend to declare each variable in a single line to initialise it, can i do that with several variables and not run into problems?

I use gcc compiler.

Comment: This is more of a opinion based question. Your team chooses a style for declaring one variable in a line to identify if someone forgot to initialize it.

Comment: By declaring multiple variables in a single line, you save the typing of type mutiple times. In my opinion, the con of single line declaration is huge when it comes to [pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3247313/4123703).

Comment: A worse issue is that of single-letter variable names:(

Comment: @MartinJames But `i, j, k` is okay for raw loops or matrix.

Comment: Using a separate declaration per variable makes it easy to add or remove variables as necessary - you just insert or remove a line.  It can also improve readability if you're declaring a mix of regular variables, pointers, and arrays - a line like `int a[N], *p, f(void);` can be a little eye-stabby.  There's a C++ convention of declaring pointers as `T* p;` (which I've ranted about elsewhere), so if you write `T* p, q;`, it looks like you may be intend for both `p` and `q` to be pointers, but only `p` will be.  Making those separate declarations makes the intent clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more of an opinion base, but I post an answer for readibility.
Declaring in a single line has pros and cons.

Pros

- Save typing for multiple times. For `int i, j , k` you saved twice of `int`.

Cons

- Forgot to initialize or assign it. Like `int i, j, k = 0`...opps only `k` has value.
- Pointer declarations `int* i, j , k` where there is only `i` is pointer. Details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3247313/4123703).

For more details, you may refer to [other C guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1262992/4123703).

Also I found [SEI CERT C Coding Standard](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/DCL04-C.+Do+not+declare+more+than+one+variable+per+declaration) confluence wiki seems good to read.